# send image to twitter via oauth

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-oauth

I am successfully able to login on twitter with oauth. Now I need to post image with status. For that I have implemented following..

```
-(void)shareontw{
    NSString *postUrl =@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json";
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postUrl]];
    [req setValue:[oAuth oAuthHeaderForMethod:@"POST" andUrl:postUrl andParams:nil] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
    NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",
                            boundary];
    [req addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *myRequestData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(globalimage, 0.8);

    [myRequestData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [myRequestData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\"dummy.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [myRequestData appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [myRequestData appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // add it to body
    [myRequestData appendData:imageData];
    [myRequestData appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [myRequestData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [myRequestData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [myRequestData appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [myRequestData appendData:[@"Success\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [myRequestData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [req setHTTPBody:myRequestData];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error from NSURLConnection: %@", error);
    }
    NSLog(@"Got HTTP status code from Twitter after posting profile image: %d", [response statusCode]);
    NSLog(@"Response string: %@", responseString);}
```

But it giving me error:  Response string: {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

I am unable to find the issue that what I am doing wrong here. Please if some has idea then help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks your above code is working fine and save a lot of time for me.i just change one line of code

this line NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(globalimage, 0.8);

replace with

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imgView.image, 0.8);

and it's working :)